# Having issues with annotations in a loop in Appcelerator

Tags: loops, annotations, appcelerator

So this is my first time working with Appcelerator's Map module and and I could use some advice on trying to make annotations appear on my map for every location I have identified. The dbArray is being passed in from another module and I have verified that there is data in the array, however I am not sure how to get it to be processed in the loop. Can anyone make any suggestions to help guide me?

```
var buildSecUI = function(dbArray){    //dbArray from data.js read function
console.log("---buildSecUI is activated---");
console.log(dbArray);

var secWin = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    layout: "vertical",
    backgroundColor: "#ffffff"
});

//building the map
var Map = require('ti.map');

var mapView = Map.createView({
    mapType: Map.NORMAL_TYPE,
    region: {latitude:25.2867, longitude:51.5333,
        latitudeDelta:0.05, longitudeDelta:0.05},
    animate:true,
    regionFit:true,
    userLocation:true
});

//array for annotations (pins for maps)
var annotations = [];

for ( var i = 0 ; i < dbArray.length; i++ ) {
// this section will create annotations and add them on the mapView
    var pin  = Map.createAnnotation({
        latitude: this.dbArray[i].lat,
        longitude: this.dbArray[i].lng,
        title: this.dbArray[i].name,
        animate:true,
        pincolor:Map.ANNOTATION_PURPLE
    });

    annotations[i] = pin;
    //annotations.push(pin);

mapView.addAnnotation(annotations[i]);  // adds annotations   
}   //for loop closure

secWin.add(mapView);
navWin.openWindow(secWin); }; //closure for buildSecUI
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. I assume that if you do a log of what you pass to createAnnotation() the data is as expected? Do you see any errors in the logs? Does it work if you just add one annotation to the map?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I believe having this. and  [i] was the incorrect thing to do, but I am trying to gain clarity

Comment: That might well be right. Since for{} is no separate scope just have dbArray[i] instead of this.dbArray[i]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop you are referring to "this.dbArray[i]", it should be just "dbArray[i]". "this.dbArray" is probably undefined.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and this was the fix. May I ask how did you know and refer topics I should look into to gain a better understanding of my mistake?

Comment: You might want to do a little more reading on what "this" actually is. In your code, dbArray was an argument which you can always access like a variable in that function. I knew "this" would be undefined because it's not normally used in that type of function.

Comment: Thanks I will do that